# Code doesn't seem to be freed for some reason plus other issues

Tags: c, malloc, free, cs50

So what's not working is that I get an error message from the cs50 course, check50, which basically tells me that it doesn't free my malloc. The exact message is as follows:

> program is free of memory errors
> can't check until a frown turns upside down

Now I have really tried to figure out what's wrong but it's been holding me up for a while, I don't get it. Now for the code: https://hastebin.com/liluyaqubo.cpp this has it.  Look at the last `//` part (unloads dictionary). I've tried to get valgrind to work but it doesn't, it is possible I don't have it. For those who are interested in what I'm doing, it is this: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/5/speller/
It's been driving me insane!

**EDIT:** here is the 100+ lines of code I wrote:
On the matter of the problem, it seems to be something about the memory not being freed properly. It seems to time out because the debugger that comes with cs50 says it can't check until a frown turns upside down (AKA it works and is good).

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include "dictionary.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node {
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
} node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 27;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

int wordcount = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word) {
    char lowercase[LENGTH + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < LENGTH + 1; i++) {
        lowercase[i] = tolower(word[i]);
    }
    node *cursor = table[hash(lowercase)];
    while (cursor != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(lowercase, cursor->word) == 0) {
            return true;
        }
        cursor = cursor->next;
    }
    return false;
}

unsigned int hash(const char *word) {
    unsigned int h = 0;
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(word + 1); i < n; i++)
        h = (h << 2) ^ word[i];
    return h % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary) {
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fscanf(file, "%s\n", word) != EOF) {
        node *tempNode = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (tempNode == NULL) {
            return false;
        }
        //tempNode->next = NULL;
        strcpy(tempNode->word, word);
        if (table[hash(word)] == NULL) {
            tempNode->next = NULL;
            table[hash(word)] = tempNode;
        } else {
            tempNode->next = table[hash(word)];
            table[hash(word)] = tempNode;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void) {
    wordcount++;
    return wordcount;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        node *tempNode = table[i];
        while (tempNode != NULL) {
            node *del = tempNode;
            tempNode = tempNode->next;
            free(del);
        }
        table[i] = NULL;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Include all necessary information in the question, not as links. Paste the code into the question, including the contents of dictionary.h (or enough of it to enable others to reproduce the problem). Prepare a [mre].

Comment: Put your code in the question. Don't put a link. And say what the problem is. Stack Overflow requires *your question* to be a much higher quality than Discord does!

Comment: We are always here to help you but we also expect something from the side of the questioner. To explain in detail where the issue lies and what you tried which doesn't work. It's not enough to just provide links to code. Provide all relevant parts inside of the question and we'll help you.

Comment: Why do you think the error message complains about the use of `free()`? I read the message as the compiler didn't found any memory issues but can't check if the code is fully correct (Which is quite normal for every compiler, f.e. in the case of undefined behavior).

Comment: Why did you use .cpp as the file extension on the original linked code, rather than .c? That may cause the code to be compiled in C++ mode.

Comment: Does it work when you run it on your own computer?

Comment: Ok, I think it's not freeing all the memory but I really don't know, I suck at this. And I didn't intend it to be .cpp but it my first time using hastebin so I must have done something wrong (as usual xD).

Comment: My humble opinion is that you just completely misunderstood the message. There is nothing saying that memory wouldn't be freed. It is even more the opposite: It says "The program is free of memory errors." - These are two sentences, but unfortunately the separation has been forgotten. It's a lexical bug in the compiler you're using.

Comment: Ok,I believe you are correct, this isn't my strong suit, I guess I saw yellow instead of green and thought it meant I was wrong....,

Comment: Do you intend to use a main function here, or is the target excecutable to be a library??

Comment: Is `n` a global variable? Maybe it's defined in `dictionary.h` but I don't know it's content. If not, this function is lacky. `n` never has been defined.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio - are you referring to `const unsigned int N = 27;`?

Comment: @ryyker OP deleted one comment before you turned up. Saying the message belongs to the `hash` function. Inside `hash`, `n` not `N`, is used but it was never defined in the shown code. Maybe it is defined in `dictionary.h` but if not, there might be a problem.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio - Oh, gottcha.  Thanks.  Do you happen to know also why nobody is talking about a missing `main()` function?  Did that/those comments disappear also?

Comment: @ryyker No, That wasn't covered before either. Missed that, Good call. But my focus was primary to find an issue in the provided code.

Comment: Im surprised you managed to see my deleted comment, it does not feature in the "dictionary.h" file. Now I gotta remember what I meant to go there...
EDIT : code sayys this : 
n = strlen(word + 1) 
In the for loop's ()

Comment: @Ragnaroni Yes, that's exactly where I meant where the problem lies. Define `n` in `hash` and see if the message disappears.

Comment: Do you mean the "unsigned int hash"?

Comment: @Ragnaroni Yes, the `hash` function.

Comment: @Ragnaroni - If you have not yet clicked the link in the very first comment, and taken some time to read it, then do what it says, asking others to fix your mess is very bad form.  As others have suggested, there are practical minimums that allows others to help, if you do not meet them in presenting your question, it just minimizes the probability of anyone actually being able to help.  Good luck.

Comment: Defining the n doesnt help the code, I'll just post it and hope that it doesnt count as a "fail", I'm sorry for this...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in your `unload()` function, it frees all nodes in the dictionary correctly and resets the hash table to all null pointers.

Conversely, here are some other problems in your code:

- The loop to turn the word to lowercase runs through the whole array whereas it should stop at the null terminator.
- the `char` argument to `tolower()` should be cast as `(unsigned char)` to avoid undefined behavior on negative values on platforms where `char` is signed.
- `hash` should compute `n` as `n = strlen(word)`, not `n = strlen(word + 1)`. Even better : you should change the loop to: `for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)`
- you should close the file before returning `false` upon memory allocation failure.
- the `fscanf` format `"%s\n"` is flawed as a word longer than `LENGTH` bytes in the dictionary will cause undefined behavior by overflowing the destination array. You can fix this with a length modifier: `"%15s"` if `LENGTH` is defined as `16`.
- the loop should stop when `fscanf()` stops returning `1`. By chance this particular conversion format can only return `1` or `EOF`, but `"%d"` would return `0` if the next character in the input stream cannot start a number.
- `load()` calls `hash()` 4 times for the same word. You should compute the hash code once and store it in a local variable.
- it is unclear why function `size()` increments the global variable `wordcount`.

Comment: @Ragnaroni: did this answer help you understand some of the issues in your code? If so, you might accept it by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score and/or upvote it.